# Primes of the form $x^2 + y^2$ can only be written as $a^2 + b^2$ in one way?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $x,y,a,b$ be distinct positive integers.
If $p=x^2 + y^2$ then $p\ne a^2+b^2$.
Is this true ? If so why ? What are the proofs for this ? I know the Fibonacci identitity : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity ,
but I do not see how it follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the basis of Eulers factorization method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_factorization_method you can find full proof enclosed. (Brahmagupta-Fibonacci is an important part of it)

Given two different sums of square representations of a number, this produces a factorization. Euler used this to factor huge mersenne numbers and break the world record for biggest prime.

Comment: If people were interested in the relation between the two answers: This one is a constructive proof in that it actually gives you a factorization and it is elementary in the sense of not using complex numbers. The proof with Z[i] only gives existence of a factorization.

Comment: +1 At the moment I accepted your answer. It was better then the other from the start. However after the edit the other answer seems improved. See my comment there.

Answer (score 10):

This is a consequence that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a UFD; since $p$ can be factored as $(x+yi)(x-yi)$, and both $x+yi$ and $x-yi$ are clearly both primes, then by unique factorization $p$ cannot be factored in any other way (up to order and unit).

Comment: I do not consider this as an answer. Primes can not be factored is clearly true.

Comment: @mick Do you understand what $\mathbb Z[i]$ is, and what a UFD is?

Comment: @mick well, this *does* answer your question. What do you mean when you write "Primes can not be factored is clearly true"?

Comment: @mick:  $p$ is a prime in $\mathbb Z$, but is not in $\mathbb Z[i]$ as a factorization has been displayed.

Comment: @mick The point is that in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, the number $p=x^2+y^2$ is _no longer_ prime; it has (non-unit) factors.  On the other hand, the number $x+yi$ _is_ prime; it has no non-unit factors.

Comment: Ok the edits done make this an answer assuming the UFD. However it seems a bit circular meaning that proving the UFD property seems to be equivalent to saying $p = x^2 + y^2$ in only one way ? Is there another way to prove UFD ? In other words assume that $p$ might(!) be the sum of $2$ squares in more ways then how to show UFD property ?
Im sorry if this is an annoying remark, but Im new to ring theory and Im picky about what I accept as proof/answer.
A good answer to this comment might change my opinion but for now I will accept the other answer.

Comment: @mick, The fact that primes equal to 1 mod 4 split in Z[i] and that it has unique factorization (sincethe points of Z[i] form a lattice you can quite easily construct a Euclidean algorithm for it) are really interesting and you can study these to get a first foothold on ring theory and algebraic number fields. See Fermats Christmas theorem on wikipedia for example.

Comment: Are you saying that the Euclidean algoritm provides a proof of UFD ? If not ; How to prove UFD ? (no wiki answer plz)

Comment: In the same way that using the Euclidean algorithm can provide a proof for unique factorization in $\mathbb{Z}$, constructing a Euclidean algorithm of sorts for $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (specifically, using norms as the values) can yield a proof of unique factorization of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ (in fact, it can be shown any commutative ring that this applies to, called a Euclidean domain, can be shown to possess unique factorization). This is the standard textbook proof of unique factorization for such domains.

Comment: @bzprules Thanks for your help. I will read up a bit when I find the time. Im not sure which answer I like best since it depends on my understanding which is at the moment clearly insufficient.

Comment: My pleasure. :)

Comment: Hmm I guess Im reading in the wrong places or Im stupid. I still do not understand how to show the UFD property. Maybe I should ask more questions relating UFD on MSE. Wiki did not help me much.